# Auto open a large swf/unity object in a new WordPress popup frame

Tags: wordpress, flash, size, themes, width

I have game site with myarcadeplugin and the Gameleon Theme in wordpress, but unfortunately, when I upload a **too large** (width) game (swf of unity), it doesn't display properly.. and very often, it brokes the end of the page below the game or doesn't display at all.

I already have modify the css for having a larger screen for larges games, but the size (the maximum width) stay apparently the same..

On my site you must be connected to play a game, so I created a login/password:
Login :    stackoverflow
password : stackoverflow

Here is a [link to a game](http://games.shost.ca/maldark-conqueror-of-all-worlds/) that **does not have a problem** and [one with a problem](http://games.shost.ca/lego-ninjago-the-final-battle/) (does not display the rest of the page).

Comment: I wasn't able to open those pages because of server latency, check them on tools.pingdom.com (a lot of yellow: "browser wait for server response"), this may be a reason of your problem.

Comment: You should post the relevant code here, check [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, when you solve the problem and your site changes, this question will not be relevant to anyone (see the guide [About]).